# Problem of running "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node"

Tags: ros, libroscpp, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I am new to ros and try to learn it by going through the beginner tutorial. However, when I tried typing the code "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node" provided in "Understandingnodes" part of the tutorial, the turtlesim window just flicked and then disappeared. I got the error message:

```
[ INFO] [1390367521.100598911]: Starting turtlesim with node name /turtlesim
[ INFO] [1390367521.107999703]: Spawning turtle [turtle1] at x=[5.544445], y=[5.544445], theta=[0.000000]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/turtlesim/turtlesim_node: symbol lookup *****error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderC1Ev*****
```

I simply cannot do anything with the turtle since I can't see the window at all. Do you guys have any idea or suggestion? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120541/problem-of-running-%22rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node%22/) by [mrq44106](https://answers.ros.org/users/11091/mrq44106/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a couple of minutes ago I also had some weird symbol lookup errors, too (After pulling some updates with the update manager).

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

together with erasing build dirs and rebuilding in my workspace by (in the catkin_ws folder:)

```
rm -r devel
rm -r build
catkin_make
```

solved the issue....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrq44106](https://answers.ros.org/users/11091/mrq44106/) on 2014-01-22**:
The turtlesim window shows up after trying your instructions. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-09-11**:
i have done the same and I can not fix it. Any ideas? The problem is the same..